# Voluntary, slave-side initiated Jenkins/Hudson slaves

Tags: jenkins, hudson

In our current team setting we have an old desktop PC running Jenkins/Hudson, and new shiny developer machines for team members. We are having a hard time buying more machines for adding slaves to the CI setup, and even harder to configure local user accounts for owning the slave process.

A solution would be that we (team members, all are local admin) install and start the slave process on our machines and "sign up" for serving as a slave until further notice.

Is there a way for Jenkins/Hudson slaves to voluntarily sign up for being a slave?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Swarm plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Swarm+Plugin) on your Jenkins master server and get volunteers to run the swarm client on their PCs.

So long as the client is running on a PC, it will automatically discover and register with the Jenkins master server, making it available for running builds.